# got "Failure: GetBucketIamPolicy must be overloaded" when gsutil iam get gs://test-bucket/ cmd is issued

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil, google-iam

Google Cloud gsutil iam get gs://testBucket command should return bucket policy, but instead received "Failure: GetBucketIamPolicy must be overloaded"

Verified storage.buckets.GetIamPolicy and storage.buckets.setIamPolicy are in placed.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That functionality only exists in the JSON API; it sounds like you've somehow managed to get gsutil to try using the XML API to make this call.

Here's the base API client class:

- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/blob/0e4bdc80f90f42edd86c3da772c22087e63b21be/gslib/cloud_api.py#L84

And here are the subclasses that implement functionality for the JSON and XML API (note that GetBucketIamPolicy is only implemented in the JSON API's client class):

- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/blob/0e4bdc80f90f42edd86c3da772c22087e63b21be/gslib/gcs_json_api.py#L334
- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/blob/0e4bdc80f90f42edd86c3da772c22087e63b21be/gslib/boto_translation.py#L160

My best guess is that you have HMAC credentials configured in your boto file, rather than OAuth2 credentials.  This will *force* gsutil to use the XML API (since HMAC credentials only work for that API), regardless of whether the command is supposed to support the XML API.  The `iam` command is [supposed to only support the JSON API](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/blob/0e4bdc80f90f42edd86c3da772c22087e63b21be/gslib/commands/iam.py#L265), but it looks like we didn't add a test for the edge case where only HMAC credentials were configured.

I've filed https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/846 to track this bug in gsutil.

Comment: so if I re-install the gcloud SDK instead of the stand alone gsutil, will that fix the credentials issue?

Comment: @Lee.Tan - reinstalling will not fix the credential issue. Instead, run the command "gcloud auth login". I would first make a copy of the `.boto` file located in your home directory. Then delete it before authenticating. This will set up new credentials.

Answer (score 1):

> "Failure: GetBucketIamPolicy must be overloaded"

This error means that the function `GetBucketIamPolicy` is not implemented in the `gsutil` program.

This indicates that the Google Cloud SDK is not installed correctly, Python is not set up correctly, or you have external libraries with name conflicts with the Google libraries.

Note: I am not confirmed this yet: yesterday there was an internal issue mentioned about gsutil. If you are using the latest version, try going back to a release from two weeks ago.

**Previous versions**

Previous versions of Cloud SDK are available in the [download archive](https://storage.cloud.google.com/cloud-sdk-release) in Google Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 0):

@mhouglum, @John Hanley I was able to replicate the issue on a different machine and the solution is to issue "gcloud config set pass_credentials_to_gsutil true" command

Like @mhouglum said, gsutil will try to read the OAuth credentials first from "gcloud auth login" but since the pass_credentials_to_gsutil" is set to false, it will read the HMAC credentials from the .boto file which doesn't support the XML API.

Thank you both for your time and efforts.